# Nodeclipse + nodemon error

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse, nodemon

When I try to run an express app in nodeclipse, it gives me the error,

> 23 Jan 11:58:04 - [33m[nodemon] v1.0.13[39m
>
> 23 Jan 11:58:04 - [33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[39m
>
> 23 Jan 11:58:04 - [33m[nodemon] watching: *.*[39m
>
> 23 Jan 11:58:04 - [32m[nodemon] starting `node
>   /home/rdteam/workspace/NedvedNodeExpressTest/app.js`[39m
>
> [31m[nodemon] unable to run executable: "node"[39m

However, when I run from command line that 
`node /home/rdteam/workspace/NedvedNodeExpressTest/app.js`
or
`nodemon /home/rdteam/workspace/NedvedNodeExpressTest/app.js`

both work without problem.

Pls help.

Regards
Hammer

Comment: How was nodemon configured in Nodeclipse Preference? How did you launch it in Eclipse? In other words: how to reproduce?

Comment: node monitor path: /usr/local/bin/nodemon  is the configuration in nodeclipse. I start the eclipse , create the project and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case (running os x) I quick solved it setting the full path in :

**/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js**

```
function run(options) {
    var cmd = config.command.raw;

    //Added line
    cmd.executable = '/usr/local/bin/node';
```

Comment: is there an issue for this yet in github?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by using the [**forever**](https://npmjs.org/package/forever) module, and configuring Nodeclipse's 'Node monitor path' to point to forever (***../npm/node_modules/forever/bin/forever***)

- `npm install forever`
- Open ***Eclipse -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse***
- Set the 'Node monitor path' to your installation of forever, and you're done.

I ran headlong into this problem whilst setting up Nodeclipse, and getting my node programs to work on Eclipse Kepler running on Mac OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 0):

The use case "Nodeclipse with nodemon":

Nodeclipse 0.9 Eclipse 4.2.2 Java 1.7 on win32

Configure Nodeclipse with monitor path `C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js`

logilog.js with `console.log('done');`

Run As -> Node with monitor

Produced command line (seen in Nodeclipse Console):

```
node --harmony C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js D:\Workspaces\ADT-Bundle\CountingServer\try\logilog.js
```

Console output

```
    23 Jan 16:23:35 - [33m[nodemon] v0.7.10[0m

      Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:\Workspaces\ADT-Bundle\CountingServer\try\undefined\nodemonCheckFsWatch1390465415226'
          at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
          at Object.watchFileChecker.check (C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js:154:22)
          at ready (C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js:49:22)
          at testAndStart (C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js:71:5)
          at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\weibl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js:847:1)
          at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
          at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
          at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
          at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
          at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
      23 Jan 16:23:35 - [33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[0m
      23 Jan 16:23:35 - [32m[nodemon] watching: D:\Workspaces\ADT-Bundle\CountingServer\try[0m
      23 Jan 16:23:35 - [nodemon] exception in nodemon killing node
```

Created issues #118 https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/118

That is how issues are reported.

Thank you for letting know that you need this. Check http://www.nodeclipse.org/ on news and how to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a **nodemon.json** config file in your application folder (e.g. `/home/rdteam/workspace/NedvedNodeExpressTest/nodemon.json`) with the following JSON it should work without having to modify the Nodemon source files.

```
{  
"exec": "/usr/local/bin/node"
}
```

This work on OS X, you may need to change the path depending on where you have node installed.

Details on Nodemon config files:
https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files